# React Authentication, is there a point in using context

Tags: reactjs, security, jwt

I have been trying to add some security to my react app. I am using a JWT token and have been storing it in the local storage. Storing it in the local storage was not very appealing for me and i decided to move the token into react context using the context API. However, after some research i learned that storing the JWT in local storage isn't that bad, and i would still need the token there in order to let the user continue after a refresh.

**So, if i am going to be storing the token there anyway, is it worth it to have a context object storing the user as well?**

It seems to me that just doing `localStorage.get("token")` is all i need.

Comment: When saved/updated in context then components that need that value will re render if it changes. When stored in local storage you need to figure out how to inform the component(s) that the value changes (if that is a requirement). But as you already figured out; you need to save it to local storage in order to keep the token between sessions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it worth it?

Both `context` and `localStorage` are using the global state, having the same token stored in both places is an anti-pattern.

What I would suggest instead is storing the `User` information in the context, and the token in the local storage.

Comment: As said below, storing the token in the local storage adds a vulnerability to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Do not store the jwt token in local storage since is vulnerable to XSS attack. So it is better using context API.

Comment: but how do I persist the token so that page refresh does not clear the token?

Comment: You don't. You have the server set a Secure, HttpOnly SameSite cookie with a refresh token that includes a sensible expiry, and have your frontend app hit the /refresh endpoint to get a new token. If the cookie is expired, you redirect to login. If it's not, you persist the new token in the context and use that.